# $x^2 \equiv -2,2 \pmod {122}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Which of the following congruences has solutions? How many?

> $$x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {122}$$
>   $$x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod {122}$$

For both congruences, $122 = 2\times61$. Hence, each congruence can be decomposed to the following: $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 2$ and $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{61}$. For the first one, $x$ has a unique solution $x = 0$. for the second one, I need to compute $\left(\frac{2}{61}\right)$ which is $-1$.

**Now** *Can I conclude that the congruence is unsolvable? Hence, there exist no solutions?*

For the second problem, the congruence $x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod {61}$ is solvable.

**Can I conclude that there is one or two solutions?**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274743/when-is-2-a-quadratic-residue-mod-p?rq=1   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670849/when-is-2-a-quadratic-residue-in-a-finite-field

Comment: And yes: from the second non-solvable congruence you can deduce the original one also has no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work with the congruence $x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod {122}$.

The ring $\mathbb Z_{122}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{61}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, as you pointed out. Now applying the isomorphism to both sides, you are looking for a solution to $(x,x')^2 = (-2,-2)$ where $x \in \mathbb Z_2$ and $x' \in \mathbb Z_{61}$.

If $\left(-2\over 61\right)=1$ then there are exactly *two* solutions to $x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod{61}$. The reason for that is because $\mathbb Z_{61}$ is a field, and the factor theorem: The polynomial $X^2+2$ has a unique factorisation $(X-a)(X-b)$ where each of $a$ and $b$ is a root of the polynomial. And the roots must be distinct because if $a$ is a root of that polynomial then so is $-a$, and the only element of a field that is the negation of itself is $0$ (unless the field has characteristic $2$).
 On the other hand, there is only one solution to $(x')^2 \equiv -2 \pmod 2$. So multiplying the number of possible values for $x$ and $x'$ gives $2$.

With the congruence $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {122}$, use the distributivity of the Legendre symbols. The Legendre symbol of $-1$ is easily shown to be $-1$ in $\mathbb Z_{61}$, showing that no solution is possible.

Comment: I had a mistake in the calculation of legendre symbol. I have updated it and would like to update your answer accordingly.

Really thankful. :)